# Copying from one variable length worksheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

Hi newbie (Very New) here,
I have a variable data from 12 sheets (Months). Each sheet shows the spend of a customer for that month, I need to somehow collate each customer onto one sheet.

Normally I would use something simple like a vlookup formula in excel but because new customers may join throughout the year I need a different way of sorting this info. As I would normally use the Account code as my vlookup source.

So I believe I need to use VBA but struggling to find where to even start on something like this.

Any helps would be appreciated.

The first thing I think would be best is to copy each month onto one master sheet then go from there. If so I think I would need to find the amount of rows in the active sheet then copy them to the master sheet but without over writing what I have already copied there.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Ja

Comment: Please think on following lines. First a unique list of customers to be dynamically updated on addition of new customer. In my view point monthly sheets are not important. It may be better to have customer wise sheet as monthly spends can be easily calculated by formulas or VBA coding. In any case your link ID will be the customer. So when either a new customer is added, his sheet is generated automatically and if any customer leaves his sheet is archived but master sheet retains his historic records. First prepare a blue print of what and how the data will flow between various data points.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the first empty row in any worksheet with the following code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet : Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName")
Dim firstEmptyRow
' Get the first empty row in column "A" by finding the last used row and adding 1.
firstEmptyRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 

ws.Range("A" & firstEmptyRow).Value = "Whatever you want to put in the first empty row"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would provide a test stub and a rough draft of the results that you are looking to achieve.  But I can still get you started.

1. This Macro loop through all the worksheet
2. Copy the Used range of each worksheet into a new workbook
3. Two addition blanks lines are added between the data
4. Followed by the Sheet Name
5. And Two more blank lines

I know nothing about the shape of your data.  But it's a good starting point.

```
Sub CombineWorksheets()
    Dim lastRow As Long, r As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set r = ws.UsedRange
        lastRow = lastRow + r.Rows.Count + 5
        wbNew.Worksheets(1).Cells(lastRow - 2, 1) = ws.Name

        r.Copy Destination:=wbNew.Worksheets(1).Cells(lastRow, 1)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I will start to play and see what I can do with the code.